# Entity Framework duplicated column issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a basic model like that :

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public Contact PrincipalContact { get; set; }
    public int? PrincipalContactId { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework creates two columns on the table `Contacts`: `Account_Id` and `AccountId`.

The column `AccountId` is always null. I don't know why I have this behavior

What is the proper way to achieve this with Entity Framework ? I tried to add the `[ForeignKey]` attribute but it doesn't change anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at how you should be creating it: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: What sort of relationship are you trying to create here between those tables? It's a little confusing looking at it.

Comment: My relationship are :
An account has multiple contacts
An account has a principal contact (wich is also in the contacts collection)
A contact has an account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Account_Id` column is created automatically by EF based in the one-to-many relationship. If you don't specify nothing, by convention, EF will recognize the fact that your Navigation property is called `Account` and your ForeignKey will be called `AccountId`, but due to you have a property with the same name, EF changes it to `Account_Id`.

To create both relationships that you need I recommend you modify the model as I show below:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public Contact PrincipalContact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, In your Context you can configure the relationships explicitly using [Fluent Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx).

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Account)
            .WithMany(e => e.Contacts)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.AccountId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
         .HasOptional(c => c.PrincipalContact)
         .WithMany()
         .Map(c => c.MapKey("PrincipalContactId"));
   }
}
```

### Update

If you want to keep the `PrincipalContactId` property on the `Account` class, you should map the relationship this way:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
   .HasOptional(c => c.PrincipalContact)
   .WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.PrincipalContactId);
```

Comment: That did the trick thank you !! Do you think it is possible to keep the "PrincipalContactId" property on the "Account" class ? It can be usefull sometimes to avoid loading the full contact.

Comment: Hello @Damien: Yes, it is possible. See the Uptade seccion in my answer. I hope this help you

Comment: Hello @Damien, If  you think that my answer satisfies your doubt, could you please, upvote my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of one-to-one relationships, you will need to provide some additional
information so that Code First knows which entity is the principal and which is
the dependent.

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PrincipalContact")]
    public int? PrincipalContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact PrincipalContact { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("AccountOf")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Account AccountOf { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I try to insert a contact or principalContact on an account this causes a DbUpdateException on db.savechanges() also the table "Contacts" has these primary keys : "Accounts_Account_id" and "Accounts_Id"

Comment: Are you dropping and creating the database on model changes?

Comment: I always delete the db manualy to be sure that it's recreated as new.