# EF Framework Code First - Not Generating the Correct DB Script

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have created my context classes and in EF.Below is the two entities I have trouble when the scripts are created from EF.
[image]

To explain the relationship between Account and the Post, basically 1 Account can have 0 or many Posts.

Below are the 3 scenarios I am specifically after, as the EF is not generating the script properly(as I understand).

1. 1 Account can create many Posts.
2. 1 Account can modify many Posts.
3. 1 Account can publish many Posts.

Below is my code for the two classes;

```
[Table("Account")]
public class Account : IModificationHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("firstName")] //db column name
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "First name should be 255 characters or less")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")] //displayed in UI
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("lastName")] //db column name
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Last name should be 255 characters or less")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")] //displayed in UI
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [Column("emailAddress")] //db column name
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Email address should be 255 characters or less")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] //for UI presentation only
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")] //displayed in UI
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address format")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [Column("role")]
    public int Role { get; set; }

    [Column("salt")]
    public string Salt { get; set; }

    [Column("dateCreated")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Column("dateModified")]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }


    public List<Post> ListPost { get; set; }

}

[Table("Post")]
public class Post : IModificationHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is mandatory")]
    [Column("title")]
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Title should be 255 characters or less")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Content is mandatory")]
    [Column("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Column("incidentID")]
    [Display(Name = "Related Incident")]
    public string IncidentID { get; set; }

    [Column("tagID")]
    [Display(Name = "Tag")]
    public string TagID { get; set; }

    [Column("dateModified")]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [Column("dateCreated")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Column("datePublished")]
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }

    [Column("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [Column("contactGroupID")]
    public int ContactGroupID { get; set; }

    //foreign key reference to Account table
    [Column("createdByAccountID")]
    public int CreatedByAcccountID { get; set; }

    //foreign key reference to Account table
    [Column("modifiedByAccountID")]
    public int ModifiedByAccountID { get; set; }        

    //foreign key reference to Account table
    [Column("publishedByAccountID")]
    public int PublishedByAccountID { get; set; }


    public Account ModifiedByAccount { get; set; }

    public Account CreatedByAccount { get; set; }

    public Account PublishedByAccount { get; set; }

}
```

when I run the add-migration command and following is the script generated by it

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Account",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    firstName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                    lastName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                    emailAddress = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                    password = c.String(nullable: false),
                    status = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    role = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    salt = c.String(),
                    dateCreated = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    dateModified = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
        
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Post",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    title = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                    content = c.String(nullable: false),
                    incidentID = c.String(),
                    tagID = c.String(),
                    dateModified = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    dateCreated = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    datePublished = c.DateTime(nullable: false),                      
                    status = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    contactGroupID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    modifiedByAccountID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    createdByAccountID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    publishedByAccountID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CreatedByAccount_ID = c.Int(),
                    Account_ID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Account", t => t.CreatedByAccount_ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Account", t => t.modifiedByAccountID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Account", t => t.publishedByAccountID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Account", t => t.Account_ID)
            .Index(t => t.modifiedByAccountID)
            .Index(t => t.publishedByAccountID)
            .Index(t => t.CreatedByAccount_ID)
            .Index(t => t.Account_ID);
```

In the script my issue is, it has created two columns "createdByAccountID = c.Int(nullable: false)" column and "CreatedByAccount_ID = c.Int()," column which I think serves the same purpose and has created another extra column "Account_ID = c.Int(),". Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong in here please ?

Thanks.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28048251/861716. And you must tell EF which ID column is the inverse end of the `public List<Post>` property.

Comment: @GertArnold: Thanks for your response. I have figured it out that I was missing the Inverse Property in my context class. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue for the above behavior from EF. It is because I haven't configured the InverseProperty.

In the Post class, I have made the below changes;

- I have removed the below properties

  ```
   [Column("createdByAccountID")]
   public int CreatedByAccountID { get; set; }

   [Column("modifiedByAccountID")]
   public int ModifiedByAccountID { get; set; }

   [Column("publishedByAccountID")]
   public int PublishedByAccountID { get; set; }
  ```
- And modified the below properties

  ```
   [Column("createdByAccountID")]
   public Account CreatedByAccount { get; set; }

   [Column("modifiedByAccountID")]
   public Account ModifiedByAccount { get; set; }

   [Column("publishedByAccountID")]
   public Account PublishedByAccount { get; set; }
  ```

And in the Account class I have made the below changes;

- Removed the following property

  ```
   public List<Post> ListPost { get; set; }
  ```
- And added the following properties

  ```
   [InverseProperty("CreatedByAccount")]
   public List<Post> ListPostCreated { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("ModifiedByAccount")]
   public List<Post> ListPostModified { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("PublishedByAccount")]
   public List<Post> ListPostPublished { get; set; }
  ```

After making the above changes, when I executed the add-migration, correct db script was generated.
Below is the script that was generated;

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.Post",
        c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                title = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                content = c.String(nullable: false),
                incidentID = c.String(),
                tagID = c.String(),
                dateModified = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                dateCreated = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                datePublished = c.DateTime(nullable: false),                      
                status = c.Int(nullable: false),
                contactGroupID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                CreatedByAccount_ID = c.Int(),
                ModifiedByAccount_ID = c.Int(),
                PublishedByAccount_ID = c.Int(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Account", t => t.CreatedByAccount_ID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Account", t => t.ModifiedByAccount_ID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Account", t => t.PublishedByAccount_ID)
        .Index(t => t.CreatedByAccount_ID)
        .Index(t => t.ModifiedByAccount_ID)
        .Index(t => t.PublishedByAccount_ID);
```

Hope this helps to someone having the same issue.

Comment: With the auto generated script, the columns were names as "CreatedByAccount_ID" as so on. How can I make those columns to be displayed in databased as "createdByAccountID" ? Should I directly edit the script generated or is there a way to do it by using the Annotations ?

Comment: Either define Foreign Key properties and map them with attributes, or configure the Shadow Properties in OnModelCreating.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#:~:text=Shadow%20properties%20are%20properties%20that%20aren%27t%20defined%20in,shouldn%27t%20be%20exposed%20on%20the%20mapped%20entity%20types.  See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864480/ef-core-5-configuring-owned-type-with-pk-same-as-fk-and-with-no-parent-property